# Eclipse Installs for nonexistent user

Tags: eclipse

Some time ago my company migrated our Windows profiles and created new ones. I had an old installation of Eclipse Neon on the old profile.

I'm now trying to install a fresh copy of the latest eclipse and it always fails because it's trying to create folders for the old Windows profile, that doesn't exist.

Here's one of the errors it reports:

```
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=1003 Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/Users/oldUser/.p2/pool.
    java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory C:\Users\oldUser\.p2\pool\plugins.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getOutputStream(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:1023)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:759)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

The folder C:\Users\oldUser does not exist anymore. Why isn't the installer installing it for the user I'm **actually** logged in as?

As far as I can tell, none of the old Eclipse Neon stuff still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it had to do with a feature called "Bundle Pools". The installer, by default, has this feature turned on - it somehow knew / remembered the previous Neon installation and was trying to write to that. Turning off the "Bundle Pools" feature during the install allowed the setup to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me after manually changing the username and home folder of my Windows 10 account, since Windows annoyingly just took the first five letters of my email, breaking paths in software I wanted to port over. I did not find an option to disable Bundle Tools per the accepted answer.

The solution was to look for and delete *[home]*/.p2/ and *[home]*/.eclipse folders in the new user folder (e.g., C:/Users/newhome/.p2, C:/Users/newhome/.eclipse) along with the eclipse installation folder before trying to reinstall. This might require enabling the viewing of hidden files and folders in Windows Explorer in order to see them. Another more tedious option if using Bundle Pools (p2) for something else would be to go through the files in this folders and edit them by hand as they will likely contain references to the old user folder that the installer picks up (or use a search tool like [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) to find references to the old user path inside files of these folders).